# Pytest: как получить имя файла/функции исполняемого теста?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Есть три файла: preconditions.py (тут я описываю поведение ДО и ПОСЛЕ прогона теста), conftest.py (тут я делаю фикстуру из прекондишенов) и непосредственно файл теста. Пример кода будет внизу. Суть в следующем. Я хочу в прекондишены засунуть лог, где будет писаться нечто в стиле "Старт теста: <ИМЯ ФАЙЛА/ИМЯ ФУНКЦИИ ТЕСТА>". Как я могу получить имя файла/функции запущенного теста? Я пытался использовать inspect: `inspect.getmodule(inspect.stack()[1][0]).__file__)`
Но столкнулся с тем, что данная конструкция выдаёт мне имя файла conftest.py, а не тест. Я менял индексы (в частности первый с 1 на 2), но получил в итоге только имя файла fixtures.py. А вот как получить имя конкретно имя теста в том или ином виде я так и не пришёл. Может кто-то помочь с этим? Или указать мне на ошибку.

Примеры кода:

**preconditions.py**

```
class Preconditions:

    @classmethod
    def setUp(cls):
        # SOME CODE BEFORRE TESTS EXECUTION
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        # SOME CODE AFTER TESTS EXECUTION
        pass
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from preconditions import Preconditions

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def testPreconditions():
    execution = Preconditions.setUp()
    binaries = Preconditions()
    yield
    binaries.tearDown()
```

**test_some_name.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('testPreconditions')
def test_some_name():
    # SOME TEST-CASE CODE
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить метаданные текущего теста можно с помощью фикстуры [`request`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#request). Пример:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def preconditions(request):
    print("test case ID:", request.node.nodeid)
    print("test case name:", request.node.name)
    print("test module name:", request.node.module.__name__)
    print("test file:", request.fspath)
    yield


@pytest.mark.usefixtures('preconditions')
def test_some_name():
    pass
```

Проблема в твоем примере в `scope='module'`. Эта фикстура будет выполняться только один раз на файл, не предоставляя информации о текущем тесте (потому что тесты из файла еще не стартовали). Измени `scope='module'` на `scope='function'` или просто убери параметр из декоратора.

Насчет конструкта с `Preconditions`: логгирование можно спокойно вести в самой фикстуре, не вынося его в отдельный класс. Но если наличие `Preconditions` является обязательным условием, то можно переписать код примерно следующим образом:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def preconditions():
    binaries = Preconditions()
    binaries.setUp()
    yield preconditions
    binaries.tearDown()
```

Эта фикстура будет вызываться один раз на каждый файл, создавая и возвращая инстанс `Preconditions`, который затем можно использовать в фикстуре `log`, которая вызывается для каждого теста:

```
@pytest.fixture
def log(request, preconditions):
    preconditions.trace(f"started test case {request.node.name}")  # например
    yield
    preconditions.trace(f"finished test case {request.node.name}")


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("log")
def test_some_name():
    pass
```